# Spring Data Neo4j 5 - Dynamic Property Creation

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am new to Spring Data Neo4j and I am development application where I will map each Neo4J Node into POJO(NodeEntity) but I need dynamic mapping between Neo4j Node and NodeEntity Class in Spring.

Example : Lets say If I have Student Node ---> is mapped to ---> Student Node Entity

```
@NodeEntity
class Student
{

@Property(name="SName")
String studentName;
.
.
.
}
```

Later instead of Student , I might get Employee Node in Neo4j with different set of properties. In that case existing Student mapping will not work with Employee Node in Neo4j.

I need generic NodeEntity class which can be mapped to any Node in Neo4j ? Is doable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @CompositeProperty annotation on a Map<String, Object> field in Your generic entity. You will be able to store different keys & values in the generic node. Check out the documentation. [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.1.0-M2/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/core/schema/CompositeProperty.html).